# Error de sintaxis en consulta SELECT con limit y offset

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente script para sql server 2008 r2:

```
SELECT *
FROM PS_GameData.dbo.Chars
LIMIT 2 offset 2
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '2'.
```

Comment: `LIMIT` no existe en SQL Server, lo equivalente es `TOP`

Comment: El equivalente de tu consulta en SQL Server sería: `SELECT *
FROM PS_GameData.dbo.Chars OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY`, revisa [este tutorial](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch/) para más detalles.

Answer (score 3):

En SQL Server no existe la instrucción `LIMIT`, desde SQL 2012 podrías usar `OFFSET N ROWS FETCH NEXT N ROWS ONLY` donde `N` equivaldría al valor que requieres para `OFFSET` y para `LIMIT` ([ver documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/order-by-and-offset-fetch-clause)).

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM PS_GameData.dbo.Chars
ORDER BY aquiLaColumnaAOrdernar -- es obligatorio
OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
```

Para SQL Server 2008 puedes hacerlo con `ROW_NUMBER()` en un CTE:

Asumo que tienes una columna `id` y ordeno  por ella:

```
;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        id, Chars,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNum
    FROM PS_GameData
    -- WHERE AQUÍ CRITERIOS SI PRECISA
)
SELECT *
FROM Results_CTE
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 3 AND 4
```

Ojo, en el `BETWEEN` la cosa cambia un poquito, el valor de la izquierda equivale al `OFFSET` y debes ponerlo sumando uno, por ejemplo, si quieres un salto de `2` debes poner `3` y a para el `LIMIT` debes sumar partiendo del `OFFSET`. O sea, `BETWEEN 3 AND 4` te mostrará los registros `3` y `4`.

Te dejo aquí un fiddle con dos ejemplos distintos:

```
CREATE TABLE PS_GameData (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    Chars VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);
```

```
INSERT INTO PS_GameData VALUES('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e'),('f'),('g');
```

```
7 rows affected
```

```
-- Versión 2012+

SELECT * 
  FROM PS_GameData 
  ORDER BY id 
  OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

| id | Chars |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | d |

```
-- Versión 2008

;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        id, Chars,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNum
    FROM PS_GameData
    -- WHERE AQUÍ CRITERIOS SI PRECISA
)
SELECT *
FROM Results_CTE
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 3 AND 4
```

| id | Chars | RowNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | c | 3 |
| 4 | d | 4 |

```
-- Versión 2012+

SELECT * 
  FROM PS_GameData 
  ORDER BY id 
  OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

| id | Chars |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | d |
| 5 | e |

```
-- Versión 2008

;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        id, Chars,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNum
    FROM PS_GameData
    -- WHERE AQUÍ CRITERIOS SI PRECISA
)
SELECT *
FROM Results_CTE
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 3 AND 5
```

| id | Chars | RowNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | c | 3 |
| 4 | d | 4 |
| 5 | e | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9zzQjEgz)